# How do I use the result of map() on a list in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have the following code:

```dart
scaleV (xs, c) => [c * xs[0], c * xs[1], c * xs[2]];

double phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2;
List<List<double>> v = [[ 0.0, -1.0, phi],
                        [-phi,  0.0, 1.0],
                        [-1.0,  phi, 0.0],
                        [ 1.0,  phi, 0.0],
                        [ phi,  0.0, 1.0]];
```

To negate each vector, I would expect I could use map(), which is a common functional construct:

```dart
var w = v.map((x) => scaleV(x, -1.0));
```

w[0], w[1], etc. are apparently not directly usable. In the browser console I get "TypeError: w.$index is not a function" when trying to use w[0]. Also "w is List" is false.

I expect this has something to do with the documentation for the map() method:

> Returns a lazy Iterable where each element e of this is replaced by the result of f(e).

But I'm not completely sure I understand this. Using List.from on the above doesn't seem to work either.

How do I use map() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, map() returns an [iterable](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Iterable.html). You can iterate over it, for example using `forEach`, but you can not access elements by their index. 
You can call `toList` to create a list of it.

```dart
var w = v.map((x) => scaleV(x, -1.0)).toList();

assert(w is List);
```

But it should also work with the [List.from](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/List.html#from) constructor. I'm not sure why isn't working, do you get an exception?

```dart
var w = new List.from(v.map((x) => scaleV(x, -1.0)));

assert(w is List);
```

Comment: I think I know why List.from() wasn't working. I think I forgot that it was a named constructor and so needs to be used with new. Anyways, thanks, I wasn't aware of toList().